# ANT uses wrong rm version

Tags: unix, ant

I want to execute ANT delete target, so that I can delete all files in the directory that mach some criteria:

```
<delete quiet="true">
    <fileset dir="${java.io.tmpdir}" includes="soapirp*.log*"/>
</delete>
```

it does not work, I think it happens because ant is trying to invoke unix rm -f command which supposed to delete file without asking me to confirm the deletion, but this does not work, i tested it by running

```
rm - f filename
```

it still prompts me for the confirmation the only way I made it work by running:

```
/usr/bin/rm -f filename
```

then eveyting works as expected , I need to tell the ant to use the different version of rm I guess but how ??

Comment: "does not work" is not going to give you a useful answer. What specifically doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: What makes you think Ant uses `rm`?  It uses the `java.io.File` API.

Comment: is your example a typo or a mistake , you have `rm - f fname` but should be `rm -f fname` (no space between '-' and 'f'). It that still prompts to remove the file, then you have an alias to rm that is forcing the '-i' option. Full path is always best for automated solutions like ant. Good luck.

Comment: OK when I say it does not work I mean it does not delete files.

Comment: The type is only in the question, I actually used rm -f filename

Comment: well if ant is using java.io.File API then it is a totally different game, I wonder why it does not delete files, they are in tmp directory?

Comment: show us the content of the directory and maybe remove the parts about linux rm in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ant` uses the Java File API to delete files, not `rm`. Your problem must be elsewhere.

(and there must be no space between `-` and `f`).